# How do you write the following strings with regex in PHP? .. and /.. and ..anyalphanumeric0

Tags: regex

I would like to write a code, that escapes everything which could mean a "parent directory" in relative path. So my code would be something like this in pseudo code:

```
if (!regex_matches(".." , template_str) && !regex_matches("*/.." , template_str) && anything else) {
    do something
}
```

Where the first regex matches exactly 2 dots, the second regex matches anything that ends with "/..", and the regex does not match any string, that has ".." in it, like "apple..banana". How to do this?

Edit: I am using PHP.

Comment: What programming language is this? Different languages have different regex capabilities.

Comment: It seems like you're confusing globs with regexp.

Comment: Check if your language has a glob matching function, that will be easier than converting them to regular expressions.

Comment: I have template string, so globs are not what I am searching for.